# Can not add ip based visitors per day in a month

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to add ip based on the current date and month, and displays it in the form of json, but after I try ip can not be added. what is lacking in my script?

sample data

```
  |      date  |     IP       
===============================
  | 2015-02-01 | 10.88.25.139 |
  | 2015-02-02 | 10.88.25.138 |
  | 2015-02-03 | 10.88.25.130 |
  | 2015-02-03 | 10.88.25.131 |
  | 2015-02-03 | 10.88.25.132 |
  | 2015-02-04 | 10.88.25.139 |
  | 2015-02-04 | 10.88.25.138 |
  | 2015-02-05 | 10.88.25.131 |
  | 2015-02-06 | 10.88.25.131 |
  | 2015-02-06 | 10.88.25.138 |
  | 2015-02-06 | 10.88.25.139 |
```

Controller

```
public function get_date_statistik() {
    for($i = 1; $i <=  date('t'); $i++) {                       
        foreach($this->my_model->get_data() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'date_on_month' => str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
                'total' => $row['total']
              );                    
        }   
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Models

```
function get_data() {
        $sql = "SELECT count(ip) as total FROM my_table WHERE DATE(date) = date('d') ";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();  
    }
```

Result

```
[{"date_on_month":"01","total":"0"},{"date_on_month":"02","total":"0"},{"date_on_month":"03","total":"0"} .........]
```

Comment: Can you please `print_r($this->my_model->get_data())` ;

Comment: I am not getting why are you calling your model in `for` loop.

Comment: @Akshay result is `Array ( [0] => Array ( [total] => 0 ) ) `

Comment: It's quite simple that your query is wrong

Comment: What data you want can you explain?

Comment: `date('d')` is a php function that cannot be executed inside of double quotes.   Either need to concatenate it or use a mysql equivalent.

Comment: Agree!!!! @Sean

Comment: @Akshay, So I want to show all the dates and total ip on that date. ex `[{"date_on_month":"04","total":"2"},{"date_on_month":"05","total":"1"},{"date_on_month":"06","total":"3"}]`

Comment: So query should bring all today's data? or you are passing date or anything ? If yes then I can't see anything you are passing(date).

Comment: not, so I just wanted to show the current date and month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your controller will be as :**

```
public function get_date_statistik() {
    for($i = 1; $i <=  date('t'); $i++) {
        $date_string = date('Y')."-".date('m')."-".$i;
        foreach($this->my_model->get_data($date_string) as $row)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'date_on_month' => str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT),
                'total' => $row['total']
              );                    
        }   
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

**Your model should be like:**

```
function get_data($date_string) {
        $sql = "SELECT count(ip) as total FROM my_table DATE_FORMAT( `date` , '%m-%d' ) = DATE_FORMAT($date_string, '%m-%d' )";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();  
    }
```

Comment: the result is the same `total: 0`. this ` FROM my_table DATE_FORMAT` not using `WHERE`

Comment: In model remove `return` and write `echo $this->db->last_query();` after `$this->db->query($sql)->result_array(); ` line

Comment: i remove return and write echo $this->db->last_query(); error

Comment: can you `echo` query which is made

Comment: the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: it's Solved thanks @Akshay, i change this `where DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d' ) = '".$date_string."'";` and issue clear

Comment: congratulations !! Now buy me a beer !! :p